# Error while using tabulate "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabulate

so, I was using tabulate to format my data in my latest project. But, it keeps giving this error and I'm not able to understand the reason behind it. Here's the code:

```
   from datetime import date
   from tabulate import tabulate
   records = []
   sno = [0,1]
   jades = [0,1]
   events = ['0',1]
   dates = ['0',1]
   for i in range(0, len(jades)):
      records.append([sno[i], jades[i], events[i], dates[i]])
        
   print(records)
   record = records[-1]
   print(record)
   print(tabulate(record, headers=["Sno.", "Jades", "Event", "Date"], tablefmt='simple'))
```

here's the output:

```
[[0, 0, '0', '0'], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kartik/Desktop/discord-bot/Rem.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(tabulate(record, headers=["Sno.", "Jades", "Event", "Date"], tablefmt='simple'))
  File "/home/kartik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 1426, in tabulate
    list_of_lists, headers = _normalize_tabular_data(
  File "/home/kartik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 1103, in _normalize_tabular_data
    rows = list(map(list, rows))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**Do note that the code which i posted is just the part which i found was causing the error. Those line numbers may differ.**

I tried figure out myself but the only thing I could come up with was this code:

```
record = [records[-1]]
```

I converted that last records into list of its own.

Please, help me understand the reason behind it. I'm kind of a beginner at python so, my question might be dumb.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), the first parameter to tabulate is an iterable of iterables or similar, like a spreadsheet. You need both rows and columns. What you passed in was just one list, so internally, it first grabs the first element ("1" in your case), thinks of that as a row, and then tries to iterate through each column, which is where the exception is raised.

When you wrap it in another set of brackets, like:

```
record = [records[-1]]
```

Then you're actually having `[[1, 1, 1, 1]]`, which is one row (the outer bracket) containing four columns (the inner bracket).

*I've never used this library, so I might have rows/columns switched here, but the concept is the same.*

Comment: Okay, I found the part where I was wrong. What I was trying to do was get the last part of that list to be displayed while I did ```records[-1]```` I forgot the result which I will get will be [1, 2, 3, 4] whereas I thought I would be getting [[1, 2, 3, 4]].

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(tabulate(records, headers=["Sno.", "Jades", "Event", "Date"], tablefmt='simple'))`

The reason is that the first argument in the tabulate function requires a type table object. In your current code, `record` is set to the last item in the records list which is an int. `Tabulate` requires a table to iterate over, so pass in the list of records

Comment: The thing was I only wants it to show the output of the last record I mean the last list it has example: the [1, 1, 1, 1] not the zero one

Answer (score 0):

try `records` no `record` here

`print(tabulate(records, headers=["Sno","Jades", "Event","Date"],tablefmt='simple'))`

its works

```
[[0, 0, '0', '0'], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
  Sno    Jades    Event    Date
-----  -------  -------  ------
    0        0        0       0
    1        1        1       1
```

Comment: The thing was I only wants it to show the output of the last record I mean the last list it has example: the [1, 1, 1, 1] not the zero one

Comment: oh ok sorry, i wanna see